# Change of variable. Integral vs continuous expectation

Tags: probability, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

Suppose, the goal is to perform a **change of variable** in **computing an expectation over continuous variable**s.

Now, I am wondering if the rules that can be applied are only the rules for change of variables in any integral or there are a set of rules also specific to expectations that one can take advantage of here?

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating an expectation by integration is ... an integration.   You may use the usual change of variables rules if you need to.